# How do browsers preview the first N frames of a gif before it is fully downloaded?

Tags: gif

I'm interested in developing a gallery on a mobile device. I noticed, for example, that the Android browser will keep repeating all the frames it currently has. How is this done?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood what you are trying to say, you want to start showing a partially downloaded animated GIF, right? This is possible because animated GIFs were designed to allow for that. Before broadband, people had to squeeze performance and the preferable way to put images on your site was interlaced images. This means that pixels do not come in a simple series but instead a low resolution of the image was possible to be rendered even before the whole image was received. As the rest of the image was downloaded, browsers could show an increasingly higher resolution image.

Perhaps those browsers you are mentioning use a similar technique.